# How to trigger Sequences on Segments?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have created a sequence through sales hub application and I have also created the segment from work assignment. The segment contains three contacts. The issue is when i run the sequence on the contact record it works fine but when I attached the same sequence with segment it does not work. Kindly help out am I missing something?

Best Regards,
Khubaib

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, you have sequence that is linked with segment. But when new Contacts get Segmented into it, sequence does not run? And also manually attaching this sequence to Contact does not make it run?

Comment: No when I attach the sequence with the segment it does not works and segment contains segmented contact list. But yes it is working with the contact records.